# how to get clob data with vb6

Tags: oracle, vb6

I want to get clob data with vb 6 . For this purpose , I have written the following code  :

```
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As String
Dim fingerdata1 As String
Dim SQL As String

Private Sub Command1_Click()
conn.Open cn
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
SQL = "select FINGERDATA from FINGERDATA"
 rs.ActiveConnection = conn
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
rs.Source = SQL
rs.Open
rs.MoveFirst ' to be safe
Do While Not rs.EOF
       fingerdata1 = rs.Fields("FINGERDATA").Value
       MsgBox (fingerdata1)
       rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
cn = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=fingerprintdata;User ID=fingerprintdata;Data Source=10.11.201.84;Persist Security Info=True"
End Sub
```

But when I am running this code , I am getting the following error :

[image]

How can I solve this error ? Please help me to get clob data from oracle in vb6 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483936/vb6-oracle-retrieving-clob-into-an-array

Comment: I read that answer .  BU t I am working with ADODB connection .

Comment: Try using the oracle native driver instead. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?549394-RESOLVED-Oracle-Blob-10G-Datatype-Not-Supported-Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me .

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As String
Dim fingerdata1 As String
Dim SQL As String

Private Sub Command1_Click()



conn.Open cn
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "select * from FINGERDATA", conn
rs.MoveFirst ' to be safe
Do While Not rs.EOF
       fingerdata1 = rs.Fields("FINGERDATA").Value
       MsgBox (fingerdata1)
       rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
cn = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=fingerprintdata;User ID=fingerprintdata;Data Source=10.11.201.84;Persist Security Info=True"
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of useless `rs.MoveFirst` you should better make `rs.Close` after loop has been finished.

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle Home Driver to retrieve data from CLOB data type.

Posted in the below on how to configure Oracle Home Driver on your machine.

[How to Handle Clob Data Type in Excel from VB SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656354/how-to-handle-clob-data-type-in-excel-from-vb-sql-query/47177283#47177283)

Answer (score 1):

I had to review a lot of posts, and here is a solution which finally worked for my case:

I had to use "Oracle in OraClient12Home1" instead of "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle", as Microsoft's does not handle CLOBs

Please note that "strSQL"  statement is to  retrieve only one CLOB value in my case.

VBA code:

```
strCon = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};DBQ=alias from your TNSNAMES.ORA ;uid=MYSUER;pwd=MYPASS;"
Connection.Open (strCon)

Results.Open strSQL

Dim strTxt As String

**strTxt = CStr(Results.Open.Fields(0).Value)**

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6).Cells(3, 1) = strTxt
```